# Get data by Id and Rank in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, linq

Here is a sample original data

```
Id      Rank
2714    1
2713    2
2712    3
2711    4
2710    5
2709    6
2708    7
2706    8
2705    9
2704    10
2703    11
2702    12
2701    13
2700    14
2699    15
2698    16
2697    17
2696    18
2695    19
2694    20
```

Now for example User give me an Id = 2705 whose rank is 9 Now I have to get data between rank 6 and rank 12 How can I do it.

Comment: Is `Rank` data continuous/adjacent (no gaps)?

Comment: How are the two queries related? Anyhow, you can add `WHERE`-condition to filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when id = 2705 then rank end) over () as the_rank
      from t
     ) t
where rank >= the_rank - 3 and rank <= the_rank + 3;
```

You can also use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where (select t2.rank from t t2 where t2.id = 2705) between t.rank - 3 and t.rank + 3;
```

As you know (because this is your data), `rank` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.  Hopefully, your actual column name is different, but if that is the name, you need to escape it.

Comment: `rank` must be quoted with backticks (reserved word).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM src_table t1
JOIN src_table t2 ON t1.`rank` BETWEEN t2.`rank` - 3 AND t2.`rank` + 3
WHERE t2.id = 2705
```